# Weird permission issue with POSIX ACLs, NFS v3 on Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs, access-control-list

I have two Linux systems, both running Debian Squeeze. Versions of (I think) the stuff involved are:

```
  kernel: 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64
  ii  nfs-kernel-server                   1:1.2.2-4squeeze2            support for NFS kernel server
  ii  libnfsidmap2                        0.23-2                       An nfs idmapping library
  ii  nfs-common                          1:1.2.2-4squeeze2            NFS support files common to client and server
  ii  portmap                             6.0.0-2                      RPC port mapper
```

(The client doesn't have `nfs-kernel-server` involved.)

I have a directory with ACLs:

```
# file: dirname
# owner: jon
# group: foogroup
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
group::r-x
group:foogroup:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:...
```

There are two users, neither one of which owns the directory:

```
uid=3001(jake) gid=3001(jake) groups=3001(jake),104(wheel),3999(foogroup)
uid=3005(nic) gid=3005(nic) groups=3005(nic),3999(foogroup)
```

The `jake` user can create files in the directory without issues. The `nic` user can't. All UIDs/GIDs are the same on the client and server. I've verified (packet sniffing) that the right uids/gids get sent via `AUTH_UNIX` are correct-- `uid=gid=3005, auxiliary gids=3005,3999`-- and that the server replies with `NFS3ERR_ACCESS`, which the kernel on the client maps to `EACCES (Permission denied)`.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Utterly gratuitous packet trace: https://gist.github.com/2728469

Comment: nfs-kernel-server is not a client service, but a server service. There's no reason to run that service unless a client is in turn sharing out some of its local data.

Comment: @Adrian it's not. See above.

Comment: Can you share your /etc/exports?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if this could cause the problem you're having, but I noticed some oddity:

Your directory is group owned by `foogroup`. `foogroup`s permission therefore is `group::r-x`. But you set an additional ACL entry `group:foogroup:rwx`. Why don't you just set `group:rwx` instead?

Even a default ACL for `group:foogroup` is unecessary as you have `setgid` on your directory. Every new directory below will therefore automatically inherit the owning group and the `setgid` of your directory.